# What conditions will the application of an AED enable a person in cardiac shock to obtain to normal heart rhythm

Tags: heart-attack, aed-defibrillator

While this always depends in practice on the person's health and internal characteristics, in general what conditions would an AED or  defibrillator solely used  actually enable normal heart rhythm from a state of cardiac arrest? I have a possible family history of aortic aneurysm (uncle had a cardiac arrest but he had no autopsy)  and I am far too young and generally healthy to stress about finding a doctor who screening but there lots of AED around my area.